# Users should login with instagram, record should be created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, instagram-api

I simply want to user `devise` + `oauth` to let users log in my app with their instagram account. i tried several tutorials, devcamp and railscast videos but just cant get it working. is there a **working** step by step guide, on how to implement omniauth for instagram with devise?

every time i want to read the docs i just get confused as instagram is pasting a LOT of code in just one block, without explaination, where this code belongs to. also they never use plain embeded ruby, instead they use haml and stuff.

for now i got this:

`omniauth_callbacks_controller:`

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
  end
end
```

`routes.rb`

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

`initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :instagram, ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET"] 
# i had plain text instead of the env tags, but it made no difference
```

in my user.rb i placed some code with session stuff i dont really understand, but it havent worked either.

Answer (score 0):

sample of code

```rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
    session["devise.instagram_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    if user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:instagram]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).take
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.instagram_data"]
        user.uid = data["uid"]
        user.provider = data["provider"]
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Full example is here https://github.com/germanescobar/rails-devise-instagram/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

Comment: thanks for your response. unfortunately it still does not work for me. i just get redirected to the `new_user_registration_path` as mentioned in the callback controller.